# Sync Git Branch to a specific folder

Tags: bash, git

Suppose I have a git repo named `waterkingdom` It has lot of branches. We will be working with a specific branch called `wave-pool`.

wave-pool branch has files & folders such as

```
cost.txt
ride.txt
rules.txt
code/
code/ride.py
code/boom/crash.py
```

We have another folder which is not a part of the repo named `wave-pool-boom`

How can I only sync the branch `wave-pool` from `waterkingdom` repo to the folder called `wave-pool-boom` after the commit without knowing the latest commit hash?
Everything is locally on Linux.

Comment: Do you want to change the contents of the folder `wave-pool-boom` to match the branch `wave-pool`, or do you want to update the branch `wave-pool` to match the contents of the folder `wave-pool-boom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I only sync the branch `wave-pool` from `waterkingdom` repo to the folder called `wave-pool-boom` after the commit without knowing the latest commit hash??
>
> Everything is locally on LINUX.

Pushing branches from one repo to another is easily done in git, and makes a lot of sense the more you work with git.

1. Clone `waterkingdom` into a new directory

```bash
git clone --single-branch -b wave-pool /path/to/waterkingdom ~/projects/waterkingdom
cd ~/projects/waterkingdom
```

2. Setup a new remote

```bash
git remote add r-wave-pool-boom /path/to/wave-pool-boom
```

3. Push the branch to the remote (but do not change its tracked remote branch)

```bash
git push r-wave-pool-boom wave-pool
```

4. Remove the remote (optional)

```bash
git remote remove r-wave-pool-boom
```

#### Tools to help you further your Git knowledge

- `git branch -avv`

Gives a listing of all branches and what remote branch (if any) they track, what the latest commit hash/message is, and the state (behind, ahead) of each branch.

- `git remote -v`

Give a listing of all the remotes (if any) and their URL's configured for your local repo.

#### Further comments

Why "without knowing the latest commit hash"? The latest commit hash is always `HEAD` or `<branch-name>` or `refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>`.